# Conditions for proving infinite codimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, moduli-space

I am working with moduli spaces of curves and I am not used to work with infinite dimensional spaces. Then I was wondering if there are sufficient explicit conditions to stablish that certain subspace $W$ has infinite co-dimension within a largen infinite-dimensional space $U$. For example, working with finite-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces, proving that $W$ is the kernel of certain function $f:U\to\mathbb{K}$ (assumming $0$ is a regular value of $f$) shows that $W$ has co-dimension $1$ in $U$. Is there any analogous result in the infinite dimension setting for proving infinite codimension? Or, any other radically different result (maybe topological...) that states conditions under which $W$ has infinite-codimension? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If $U$ is any vector space  of non-$0$ dimension and if $f:U\to F$ is linear, where $F$ is any field, and if $f\ne 0,$ then $f^{-1}\{0\} $ has co-dimension $1$ in $U$. That's all that comes to mind for me.